# Activity memory usage

Tags: android, android-activity, memory, memory-management, android-fragmentactivity

I have a simple activity with a RelativeLayout and, centered in it, a button that calls recreate() at onClick.
In my activity's onResume I call this method:

```
private void showFreeMemory() {
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    Log.e("Test",availableMegs + " MB")
}
```

I've noticed that every time I recreate activity (by clicking the button) available memory is (extremly) less than the previous one time.
For example:
335 MB first time, 317 MB the second, 296 the third, ecc...about 20 MB decrementation per time.
The same if I call finish and re-launch activity.

Then I've tried to switch my activity in a FragmentActivity and load my layout in a fragment. In this case just 0 or 1 MB decrementation per time.
How is it possible? There is a way to obtain no decrementation using Activity (without switching to FragmentActivity and Fragment)?

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak, probably of the Activity object itself (recreate causes a new activity to be made).

Comment: I've found the real cause. The interstitial (loaded at onCreate) accumulates memory usage and never release it, even if com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd java object becomes elegible by gc.